# Rails - How To Create Various Layouts For a Data Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

For my application, I have users who can create team pages and then create team members that is displayed on the team pages.  Right now, I render the team members on my team pages fine, with no issues.

My question is how I can render the team members in different layouts?  Should I create a file called team_members/_team_memberv2.html.erb with a different layout of the team_member data? If so, how do I call the rendering and setup the controller? Thanks!

**CURRENT SETUP:**

**teams_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @team_members = @project.team_members.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end
```

**_teaminfo.html.erb**

```
<!-- Show Team -->
<% if @team.team_members.blank? %>     
  <p>No team members have been added to this project.</p>        
<% else %>        
  <%= render @team_members %>
<% end %>
```

**team_members/_team_member.html.erb**

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left">
    <img class="media-object" data-src= <%= image_tag team_member.teamuserimage_url(:thumb).to_s %>
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><%= team_member.membername %></h4>
    <%= team_member.content %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render in a different layout, I would replace "<%= render @team_members %>" with the following:

```
<% @team_members.each do |team_member| %>
    <%= team_member.membername %>
<% end %>
```

From here, I can style it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of partial.

it would be like

```
<%= render "team_member" %>
```

then do your output like normal in the partial.

I'm not sure you have to pass the local variable of @team_member or not.

if so:

```
<%= render partial: "team_member", locals: { team_member: @team_member } %>
```

and get your data

```
<% @team_member = local_assigns[:team_member] %>
```